# Get Position of Drag & Drop Element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

i am using the following code: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-a-group-with-kineticjs/ for Drag & Drop.

My question is: How can i get the actual position (x,y) of a group after being dragged and dropped?

Answer (score 1):

You can use events of kinetic objects - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/
In your case - 'dragend'.

```
group.on('dragend',function(){
    console.log(group.getPosition());
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/xEsDZ/

Comment: I would have thought this would work too.  But in fact, getPosition().x produces inconsistent and unreliable information for group drags.  Similar problems with group.getX() and group.getAbsolutePosition().x    :(

Comment: What you mean "inconsistent and unreliable"? I am using this in my project for groups and everything works fine.

Comment: Check this fork of your fiddle which shows the group.getPosition().x after each dragend: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/xEsDZ/3/  As far as I can tell, it's both inconsistent and unreliable.  As always, I want to learn, so if you have some magic please teach me!  :)

Comment: Yes. It is some magic here.   getPosition return position RELATIVE to parent. In your case group is parent of rect. So.. When you created group, it had coords  {x : 0, y : 0} (default values). Rect had coords {x:50, y :50}, BUT this is coordinates inside group, not inside layer. You have to do this. Set {x:0,y:0} to rect and {x:50,y:50} to group.

Comment: Try to alert rect coordinates. It is not changing after dragging. As I said rect is not moving inside group, but group moving inside layer.